# XStream Illegal reflective access Problem after upgraded to java 10

Tags: java, xstream

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING:
>   Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
>   (file:libraries/xstream-1.4.10.jar)
>   to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator

Comment: Perhaps this will help:  https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/issues/101

Comment: I experience this error with maven project. After upgrading to the most recent versions maven-compiler-plugin (v3.8.1), maven-war-plugin(v3.2.3) and maven-dependency-plugin(v3.1.2), this error stopped showing